# When sending a string with websocket-client output indicates I'm sending binary

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, encode

I want to send a string via an open websocket, but websocket-client seems to send binary instead. I'm also now sure whether to prefer websocket-client or websockets egg in python. As I never tried asynchronous programming before and websockets seems to require this I'll better stick to websocket-client I guess.

I know about "classic" http and try to learn how to use websockets now. So I want to send simple strings to a server using echo.websocket.org

```py
on_open function:
def on_open(ws):
    ws.send("")
    ws.send("I'm blue")
    ws.send("")
    ws.send("I'm blue")
    exit()

CLI output:
--- request header ---
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: echo.websocket.org
Origin: http://echo.websocket.org
Sec-WebSocket-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13


-----------------------
--- response header ---
HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake
Connection: Upgrade
Date: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
Server: Kaazing Gateway
Upgrade: websocket
-----------------------
send: b'\x81\x80}0\xa2\xb9'
send: b'\x81\x88\xc1\xca\xcbU\x88\xed\xa6u\xa3\xa6\xbe0'
send: b'\x81\x80V6&\xfc'
send: b'\x81\x88\x82\xfd\n\xb9\xcb\xdag\x99\xe0\x91\x7f\xdc'
```

I would expect either the strings being send or at least being part of what is being sent. blue for example translates to hex 626c7565 (ascii-code)